# Creating an empty NSArray

Tags: arrays, nsmutablearray, initialization, nsarray, declaration

in C I can simply declare an array like this:

```
int array[500];
```

to declare an array of size 500 which can then be filled later. Is it possibel to do the same thing in NSArray? I understand for the NSMutableArray there is the arrayWithCapacity class method to "create" and empty array (or at least declare the array to be filled later). Is there a way to do something similar for NSArray, since I know the exact size of my array I want to fill in the contents later in a "for" loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, `int array[500];` does not create an empty array - it creates an array full of zeros. Since `NSArray`s is immutable, you do need to use `NSMutableArray` if you'd like to be able to populate it later.

You can make an array with a specific capacity, and then put objects into it, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:500];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 500 ; i++) {
     [array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

Since `NSMutableArray` is an `NSArray`, you can create it in a method as `NSMutableArray*`, and then return it as `NSArray*` to the callers.

Comment: This answer has an issue. As stated in the documentation for `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`: "count is the number of values from the objects C array to include in the new array. This number will be the count of the new array. **It must not be negative or greater than the number of elements in objects**."

Comment: @DavePeck OMG, I cannot believe nobody has noticed this before! Thanks for the comment!